# Multipole expansion of Coulomb function in 2D (Laplace expansion)

Tags: special-functions, generating-functions, greens-function, laplace-expansion

In 3D, Coulomb function in Cartesian coordinates $(x, y, z)$ reads

$$\frac{1}{|\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{x'}|} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-x')^2 + (y-y')^2 + (z-z')^2}}$$

which may be expanded in spherical coordinates $(r, \theta, \phi)$ with Legendre polynomials (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function_for_the_three-variable_Laplace_equation)) or spherical harmonics (see [here](http://www.physicspages.com/2012/02/20/multipole-expansion-in-electrostatics/)) in [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion_(potential)).

Consider function in 2D

$$\frac{1}{|\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{x'}|} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-x')^2 + (y-y')^2}}$$

What forms of expansion in Cartesian coordinates  $(x, y)$ or polar coordinates  $(r, \theta)$?

What special functions used?

Comment: As far as I know (I might be wrong)  You can generally expand any function in terms of whatever basis you are considering. For example you proposed the expansion of the function $1/|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'|$ in terms of spherical harmonics. The Legendre polynomials are a particular case of the spherical harmonics (naturally arise when considering symmetrical functions wrt. an axis). Therefore the 2D solution might be seen as a symmetric 3D solution wrt. one axis and thus can be expanded also with Legendre polynomials.

Comment: This isn't actually a solution to Coulomb's (i.e. Laplace's) equation in two dimensions: that would be $\log{\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2}}$.

Comment: @Chappers Sure, it is not solution to Laplace in 2D. But I am interested in expansion of $1/\sqrt{(x-x')^2 + (y-y')^2}$. Do you know of such an expansion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Laplace expansion will work: since
$$ \frac{1}{\lvert (r\cos{\theta},r\sin{\theta})-(r'\cos{\theta'},r'\sin{\theta'}) \rvert} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos{(\theta-\theta')}}}, $$
one has
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos{(\theta-\theta')}}} = \frac{1}{r}\sum_{l \geq 0} \left( \frac{r'}{r}\right)^l P_{l}(\cos{(\theta-\theta')}), $$
since the left-hand side is always the generating function of the Legendre polynomials, whatever the dimension. That's fine, but while one can apply the formula
$$P_l(\cos{\theta}) = \frac{4\pi}{2l+1} \sum_{m=-l}^l Y^{-m}_l(\theta,0)Y^{m}_l(\theta',0), $$
it's rather low on physical meaning: it seems to suggest we are working on a great circle on the sphere, rather than in the plane proper.

On the other hand, the coordinate-free expansion of
$$ \frac{1}{\lvert \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'\rvert} = \frac{1}{\lvert \mathbf{x}\rvert} \left(1 -\frac{2\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{x}'}{\lvert \mathbf{x}\rvert^2} + \frac{\lvert \mathbf{x}'\rvert^2}{\lvert \mathbf{x}\rvert^2}  \right)^{-1/2} $$
using the binomial expansion works in exactly the same way, except that the expansion is no longer has traceless tensor in the $r^{-5}$ term: $3r_ir_j-\delta_{ij}r^2$ has nonzero trace for $d \neq 3$.